# Can I use an aggregate function without rollup that is caused by group by?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, aggregate

For a given table

```
 a   b   c
---|---|---
 1   2   3
 1   4   5
 2   6   7
```

Query

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(a) as d
GROUP BY
   a
```

Returns

```
 d   b   c
---|---|---
 2   2   3
 1   6   7
```

And I would like to have `b` and `c` column values to stay visible. I need to use `COUNT` but that's impossible without using a `GROUP BY`.  **Is there a way to get a following result from the starting table:**

```
 d   b   c
---|---|---
 2   2   3
 2   4   5
 1   6   7
```

`d` column values represent what `COUNT(a)` would return without rolling up (grouping) the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table if exists t;
CREATE TABLE t (a int, b int, c int); 
Insert Into t values
(1,   2 ,  3),
( 1,   4 ,  5),
( 2 ,  6  , 7);

select d, b, c 
  from t 
     left join 
       (SELECT a, COUNT(a) as d 
          from t
          GROUP BY a) t1 
     on t1.a = t.a
```

[example on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/920ff3/1)

Comment: Thank you, that was beautiful